# Why won't the message edit embed send when a message is edited? (discord.py)

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

My log embed isn't sending when a message is edited. Does anyone see why?

```
@client.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    with open('logchannel.json', 'r') as f:
        logs = json.load(f)

    logchannel = discord.utils.get(logs)
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0x0000ff, title="Message Edited", description=f"{before.author.mention} edited a message.")
    embed.add_field(name="Original Message", value=before.content, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Edited Version", value=after.content, inline=True)   
    await logchannel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Your code should work fine, are you getting any errors, have you tried debugging?

Answer (score 0):

`discord.utils.get` is for getting an element with specified attributes from an iterable. You're looking for `discord.Client.get_channel`.

Also, `r` mode and `inline=True` are unnecessary. They are implied.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    with open('logchannel.json') as f:
       logs = json.load(f)

    logchannel = client.get_channel(logs)
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0x0000ff, title='Message Edited', description=f'{before.author.mention} edited a message.')
    embed.add_field(name='Original Message', value=before.content)
    embed.add_field(name='Edited Version', value=after.content)
    await logchannel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: I did all that and now I have this error:

Ignoring exception in on_message_edit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "asmusic.py", line 204, in on_message_edit
    break
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Comment: @TheSuperRobert2610 What is the content of `logchannel.json`?

Comment: It has the guild ID, and the selected channel ID

Comment: @TheSuperRobert2610 Not enough context. I need the actual content, if you don't want to share the IDs you can replace them with like `guild_id` and `channel_id`

Comment: Ok, here it is: `"797921708861423640": 797921708861423643`

Comment: Try changing it to just `797921708861423643`. The could should work then

Comment: The guild ID is in quotation marks, and the channel ID isn't

Comment: This is a .json file, not a .txt, and it says it needs a colon next to the channel ID

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233850/discussion-between-makonede-and-thesuperrobert2610).